# How does fungi network transfer substances between plants?

Tags: mycology, bio-mechanics, network

**How does fungi network transfer substances between plants?**

I recently read a short article about fungi network. And I am wondering  about how fungi network works (Mechanism).

> Plants have fungi network. And a plant which lost it gets prone to insects.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhizal_network)